# Changing a:hover on li:first child

Tags: html, css, hover, css-selectors

I'm trying to make the first link in an unordered list have a special hover attribute

like

**li:first-child a:hover{code here}**

but it's not working. I also tried

**li a:hover:first-child{code here}**

but it just changed the a:hover for all the lis.

I can't change the list at all. It's automated from another site (boards2go.com) that I'm applying CSS too and there's no special class names for the lists, so I'm trying to work around it.

Ideally, I'd like my list to go like this:

**-item one [has special modification]**

*-item two [uses the regular a:hover css]*

*-item three [uses the regular a:hover css]*

The actual css is a little more involved than a simple bold vs. italic but you get my meaning.

Comment: we need to see your HTML structure :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by my HTML structure? The HTML itself is not my own, it's the other website's.

Comment: http://www.boards2go.com/boards/board.cgi?user=mmzjoinme -- this is what I'm trying to alter. I'm trying to make the first post of each thread have a special hover attribute and the rest follow the normal css

Comment: Send link then - this code is working. Some css collision is in question, probably....

Comment: Looking at your linked page, `first-child` won't work for you (especially since you can't change the HTML) because the `li` is not the first child. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the link you provided: http://www.boards2go.com/boards/board.cgi?user=mmzjoinme

`li:first-child a:hover{code here}` doesn't work because the `li` is not the first child of its parent element. The first child of its parent element (the `ul`) happens to be `<br>` ([which is not good HTML, `li` elements should be the only children of `ul` besides script-supporting elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)). You can learn more about how the `first-child` selector works here: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child)

To fix this, you can use the `first-of-type` selector in conjunction with some more specific targeting.

Browser Support for `first-of-type`: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

**CSS:**

```
.b2g_posts_container > ul > li:first-of-type a:hover
{
    background-color: orange;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/4MMWP/

*- or -*

**CSS:**

```
ul > li:first-of-type a:hover
{
    background-color: orange;
}

li > ul > li:first-of-type a:hover
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/4MMWP/1/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/826xZ/ using

```
li:first-child a:hover { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

Comment: That's weird. When I tried that, it didn't work.
I tried it again. Now it's backwards. The first child is purple and the rest are red while it's supposed to be red then purple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, working fine. Obviously without seeing your code, it's hard to know what you mean exactly

http://jsfiddle.net/36dQz/

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
ul.firstlinkhover li:first-child a:hover
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal!important;
}
ul.firstlinkhover a:hover
{
    font-style: italic;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="firstlinkhover">
<li><a href="#">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#">One</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```